# Recommended way to locate parent element in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, protractor

According to the newly published [Style Guide](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#never-use-xpath), *using the `by.xpath()` locators is considered a bad practice*. I'm actually trying to follow the suggestion, but stuck on getting a parent element.

Currently we are using `..` XPath expression to get to the element's parent:

```
this.dashboard = element(by.linkText("Dashboard")).element(by.xpath(".."));
```

How can I locate the element's parent using *other* built into Protractor/WebDriverJS locators?

Comment: As far as I know, xpath with expression ".." is the only way to get parent of the element. I usually use cssSelector to find element but I still have to use xpath to get their parent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I dig the Style Guide, and agree that xpath is to be avoided, there's always an exception that proves the rule. I think this is one of those cases :)

Comment: I agree with @quirimmo, that this exception is no longer valid. [Find here an inofficial doc about parentElementFinder](http://w3cgeek.com/locating-parent-elements-with-parentelementarrayfinder.html)

Comment: One other minor note to support this being an exception to avoiding xpath... If you get an element using browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement(), then parentElementArrayFinder is not available, but findElement(by.xpath('..')) is available.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, at the moment there is an easier way to select the parent of an element avoiding to use `xpath`.
From an `ElementFinder` you can simply access the parent element through `parentElementArrayFinder` and then for example trigger the `click` method:

`myElement.parentElementArrayFinder.click();`