# Protractor Implementation in Angular2 without using ids

Tags: protractor

I have application in Angularjs2, and developers have not been using ids into it. Now I have to implement the Protractor on same application. Is there anyway to implement the Protractor without using "absolute XPath"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: more elaborate explanation and/or code samples would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no AngularJS2 ... it's either Angular(2+) or AngularJS(v1.x).

Answer (score 0):

Please find a huge range of locator-possibilities on the [official Protractortest API Page](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder)

Every element on a page needs to be uniquely identifiable... else the page wouldn't work, no matter which technology. Therefore with the help of any of the above provided locator-possibilities you'll always find the element you're looking for.

And there is never a need for XPath, [except for this only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35237709/recommended-way-to-locate-parent-element-in-protractor). (though there is an [parentElementArrayFinder introduced in the meantime](http://w3cgeek.com/locating-parent-elements-with-parentelementarrayfinder.html), so not even that one exception is valid anymore)

**UDPATE**

If you could use XPath, you can for sure use CSS-Locators.

**Here some examples for locators:**

- `$('div.class#id[anyAttribute="anyValue"] div.child.somewhere-below-div-point-class')`
- `element(by.cssContainingText('div[data-index="2"]', 'select this option'))`

Or as a specific example the "Learn More" of the "Tree List" section of https://js.devexpress.com/ :

```
treeListSection = element(by.cssContainingText('div.tab-content h2', 'Tree List')).getDriver();
learnMoreBtn = treeListSection.element(by.cssContainingText('a.tab-button','Learn More'));
learnMoreBtn.click();
```

Those are just examples, but there is always a way to do it. 
If you provide some example-HTML in your Question, I can direct you towards a solution.

**UPDATE 2**
For getting the Parent Web Element, one could [use `getDriver()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getDriver) as well

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But they have used every where devextreme for each form. Now the forms are creating dynamically, unfortunately we can not use locator-possibilities. Any more suggestions ??

Comment: As I said... every page has elements, that are uniquely identifiable (else your backend wouldn't know, how to connect the information to the elements)... no matter how dynamic the framework is. I updated my answer with some examples. Maybe you can update your question with some example from your side as well?

Comment: glad to hear. Be so kind and mark my answer as the correct one, if you feel that it helped.

Comment: Hey Ernst, Can you please help in one more thing.

Actually I want to access an outside into another file. For example:
My folder structure is like this:
Homepage:
 Page1:
  Page2:
   page2spec.js
spec.js
conf.js

Homepage has (Page1, spec.js and conf.js), inside homepage folder structure is like (Page2) inside page2 folder structure is like (page2spec.js)

Now I have created class into spec.js and I want to use that class inside the page2spec.js, and the folder structure is like above. I tried to use require but it does not working. Can you please help me on this?